# With flushSync() inside useEffect do we do the same as using useLayoutEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#flushsync

> Force React to flush any updates inside the provided callback
> **synchronously**. This ensures that the DOM is updated immediately.

```
// Force this state update to be synchronous.
flushSync(() => {
  setCount(count + 1);
});
// By this point, DOM is updated.
```

Knowing that, it is the same as using useLayoutEffect, or **do I misunderstand flushSync()**?

```
const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = React.useState("Leonardo");
    React.useEffect(() => {
        ReactDOM.flushSync(() => {
            for (let index = 1; index <= 100000; index++) { // for simulate blocking
                console.log(index);
            }
            setName("Jose");
        });
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello {name}</h1>
        </div>
    );
};
```

¿it is the same that this?

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  for (let index = 1; index <= 100000; index++) {
   console.log(index);
  }
  setName("Jose");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useLayoutEffect is useful for things that need to happen before paint your dom or when your code is causing flickering. it's already synchronous and executed always before every useEffect hook in your code.

flushSync is used to convert the setState into synchronous. in 99% of cases you will use flushSync  inside a handler like a form submit handler, outside of useEffect to execute an imperative action

```
function handleSubmit(values) {
  flushSync(() => {
   setForm(values);
  });
}
```

Be aware that flushSync force a re-rendering, so use it carefully

The common use case of flushSync is update the DOM after settings the state immediately. example scroll to the new added element in the list

```
 flushSync(() => {
   setElements((elements) => [
    ...elements,
    {
      id: 'random',
    },
   ]);
 });
 // scroll to element here
```

Check this example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-18-batching-updates-flushsync-forked-vlrbq8. you can delete flushSync and see the diff

Comment: Hi @Fateh Mohamed "flushSync is used to convert the setState into synchronous" - Does that mean that even with useEffect and flushSync() it will still occur after painting the DOM?

Comment: So, What's the sense of flushSync()? After paint DOM, what can it block?

Comment: Check my update i added a use case fro fluchSync

Comment: flushSync means wait until the DOM is updated with the new state,  setState will not wait for the DOM to be updated, React can updated the dom with multiple setStates... but using flushSync is a strict order to wait for the dom to be updated with the setState that is inside it and then perfrom the following actions ...

Comment: in 99% of cases you will use flushSync inside useEffect ?!!!

Comment: It was a mistake, outside, i gave an example of using it in handler events where i use it the most

Comment: @Fateh Mohamed "flushSync is a strict order to wait for the dom to be updated with the setState that is inside it and then perfrom the following actions" - does that mean that if the setState('newState') is on line 6 below then later on line 7 the state will already be updated in this case to 'newState' to do anything with that 'newState'?

Comment: I didn't get your question but React groups multiple state updates into a single re-render. flushSync tells react to re-render after the state changes that you define.

Comment: @Fateh Mohamed check my answer. please

Comment: hi @Fateh Mohamed +1 , when you say that after `flushSync()` you have the DOM updated with the new state, operating with that updated DOM only makes sense **inside the handler event where the `flushSync()`s are**, since outside the handler the DOM will be already updated **with or without `flushSync()`**, right?

Comment: There is one state and one Dom  and it is always updated with or without flushSync when the state changes. React has a strategy for more performance to gather multiple setState and render once.  flushSync is like saying, "hey, i have an emergency, i need to trigger a manual re-render now with this new state" so it's synchronous and that will pain the new DOM immediately.

Comment: And yes it has more sense inside the handler because we did a flushSync for a reason. for example scroll to the last element of a list after adding a new one. we use flushSync to render the dom (paint it) the scroll to the last element.

Answer (score 1):

They are not same. Your code might give the same performance, functional, and results, yet they are different in nature.
`flushSync` is a low-level API that flushes updates to the React DOM immediately, bypassing the normal scheduling mechanism. It should be used sparingly and only when necessary, as it can lead to poor performance and is more prone to bugs and inconsistencies. On the other hand, `useLayoutEffect` is a higher-level hook that schedules a DOM update to happen synchronously after all other updates have been processed. It is generally the preferred way to ensure that updates are synchronized with the layout of the page.

Answer (score 0):

`flushSync` is used to force React to flush a state update and when you try to put it inside `useEffect` it won't affect when `useEffect` is invoked, it will always be **after** the changes have been reflected on the browser, whereas `useLayoutEffect` is invoked **before**  and this is the main difference between them.

so `flushSync` is not a function that is supposed to be executed inside `useEffect` you will even get this warning

> Warning: flushSync was called from inside a lifecycle method. React cannot flush when React is already rendered. Consider moving this call to a scheduler task or microtask.

Comment: hi  @Ahmed Sbai "to flush a state update" here, in this context, "flush" means  something like "trigger a state update", I have always been confused by that verb

Comment: @Coder23 state update and immediately  update the DOM which is not the case if you use setState outside flushSync callback

Comment: yes that's it, if you have a function that updates 2 useState hooks, after the function completes, the component will render with the new values of your hooks, but when you do each update in `flushSync`, each update will result in a new render so the component will render twice the first time with only the first hook updated and the second time with the second updated

Comment: @Ahmed Sbai check my answer. please

Comment: hi @Ahmed Sbai +1 "flushSync was called from inside a lifecycle method" - in case of hooks, the **only** life-cycle methods are the **top-level of the function component**, a **useEffect** or/and **useLayoutEffect**, ¿right?

Answer (score 0):

I did this code to see if I understood everything, please correct me:

```
function App2() {
    const [c, setC] = React.useState(0);
    const inc1 = () => {

      /*setC is asynchronous (withoutFlushSync), so it continues the 
      code downwards and therefore from the DOM it 
      brings us the value without increment in 1*/
      setC((c) => c + 1);

      console.log(document.getElementById("myId").innerText); // old value from DOM
      console.log(c); // However below log will still point to old value ***BECAUSE OF CLOSURE***
    };

    const inc2 = () => {
      /*waits until the DOM is modified with the new state (in the first click
      c = 1)*/
      ReactDOM.flushSync(() => { // Wait
        setC((c) => c + 1);
      });

      /* brings the c = 1 of the DOM because it waited until the DOM 
      was modified with the new state incremented by one. */
      console.log(document.getElementById("myId").innerText); // new value from DOM 

      console.log(c); // However below log will still point to old value ***BECAUSE OF CLOSURE***
    };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        Count: <div id="myId">{c}</div>
        <button onClick={inc1}>without flushSync</button>
        <button onClick={inc2}>with flushSync</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yes this is right. flushSync update the dom with the new value of c the force a rendering (painting the view)

Comment: Here is a real world example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-18-batching-updates-flushsync-forked-vlrbq8?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: great @Fateh Mohamed, thank you very much for your support and patience. Marked as final answer